# How to remove kth element in O(1) time complexity

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Given a string  I need to remove the smallest character and return the sum of indices of removed charecter.
Suppose the string is 'abcab' I need to remove first **a** at index 1.
We are left with 'bcab'. Now remove again a which is smallest in remaining string and is at index 3
We are left with 'bcb'.
In the same way remove b at index 1,then remove again b from 'cb' at index 2 and finally remove c

Total of all indices is 1+3+1+2+1=8
Question is simple but we need to do it in O(n). for that I need to remove kth element in O(1). In python del list[index] has time complexity O(n).
How can I delete in constant time using python

**Edit**

This is the exact question

You are given a string S of size N. Assume that count is equal to 0.

Your task is the remove all the N elements of string S by performing the following operation N times

• In a single operation, select an alphabetically smallest character in S, for example, Remove from S and add its index to count. If multiple characters such as c exist, then select that has the smallest index.

Print the value of count.

Note Consider 1-based indexing

Solve the problem for T test cases

Input format

The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases • The first line of each test case contains an integer N denoting the size of string S

• The second line of each test case contains a string S

Output format

For each test case print a single line containing one integer denoting the value of count

1<T, N < 10^5

• S contains only lowercase English alphabets

Sum of N over all test cases does not exceed 10

Sample input 1

5

abcab

Sample Output1

8

Explanation

The operations occur in the following order

Current string S= abcab', The alphabetically smallest character of s is 'a As there are 2 occurrences of a, we choose the first occurrence. Its Index 1 will be added to the count and a will be removed. Therefore, S becomes bcab

a will.be removed from 5 (bcab) and 3 will.be added to count

The first occurrence of b will be removed from (bcb) and 1 will be added to count.

b will be removed from s (cb) and 2 will be added to count

c will be removed from 5 (c) and 1 will be added to count

Comment: Is the string limited to characters `a` - `z`?

Comment: Yes it is limited to a-z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please link to the original problem statement, or copy/paste exactly what it says, without trying to explain it.  As is, what you're asking for is impossible.

Forget deleting: if what you're asking for was possible, sorting would be worse-case `O(n)` (remove the minimum remaining `n` times, at `O(1)` cost for each), but it's well known that comparison-based sorting cannot do better than worst case `O(n log n)`.

One bet: the original problem statement doesn't require that you delete anything - but instead that you return the result **as if** you had deleted.

### With one pass over the input

Putting together various ideas, the final index of a character is one more than the number of larger characters seen before it. So it's possible to do this in one left-to-right pass over the input, using `O(1)` storage and `O(n)` time, while deleting nothing:

```
def crunch(s):
    neq = [0] * 26
    result = 0
    orda = ord('a')
    for ch in map(ord, s):
        ch -= orda
        result += sum(neq[i] for i in range(ch + 1, 26)) + 1
        neq[ch] += 1
    return result
```

For your original:

```
>>> crunch('abcab')
8
```

But it's also possible to process arbitary iterables one character at a time:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain
>>> crunch(chain(repeat('y', 1000000), 'xz'))
2000002
```

`x` is originally at (1-based) index 1000001, which accounts for half the result. Then each of a million 'y's is conceptually deleted, each at index 1. Finally 'z' is at index 1, for a grand total of 2000002.

Comment: I cannot give u the link as it was asked in a contest which is now over. And if not in O(1) can we delete kth element better than O(n). The question is same as I have stated above. It is not necessary to delete anything so what other approach we can have?

Comment: Already answered the question you asked: it's impossible. I'm not going to iteratively pull teeth ;-) trying to provoke you into reconstructing the _actual_ problem statement. For example, you later added that it's restricted to 26 possible values. That's important!  Add that to the original question, and remove irrelevant stuff (for example, the seemingly useless requirement to _actually_ delete values as you go along).

Comment: It's worth noting that even though this is one pass, it will require a comparable to a multi pass algorithm number of instructions, because on average in each iteration of the main loop the inner loop will execute 25/2 = 12.5 steps. Still in practice this would work significantly better than a 26 pass algorithm due to better cache locality, especially for long strings.

Comment: Indeed, it will work on strings too large to fit on disk, let alone in RAM ;-)

Comment: I have added the exact question. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

If you follow your procedure of repeatedly removing the first occurrence of the smallest character, then each character's index -- when you remove it -- is the number of preceding *larger* characters in the original string plus one.

So what you really need to do is find, for each character, the number of preceding larger characters, and then add up all those counts.

There are only 26 characters, so you can do this as you go with 26 counters.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're only interested in the resulting sum of indices and don't need to simulate this algorithm step by step.
In which case you could compute the result in the following way:
For each letter from `a` to `z`:

1. Have a counter of already removed letters set to 0
2. Iterate over the string and if you encounter the current letter add `current_index - already_removed_counter` to the result.
   2a. If you encounter current or earlier (smaller) letter increase the counter as it already has been removed

The time complexity is 26 * O{n} which is O{n}.

Comment: Good solution. I was too lazy to come up with an idea on how to treat the earlier removed characters, so i've opted for a simpler approach. But it turns out that avoiding deletion is easier than I though! I've updated my pseudocode to incorporate your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 26 distinct chatacters in the string, we can take each character separately and linearly traverse the string to find all its occurences. Keep a counter of how many chacters were found. Each time an occurence of a given character is found display its index decreased by the counter. Before switching to a new character, remove all the occurences of the previous one - this can be done in linear time.

```
res = 0
for c in 'a' .. 'z'
  cnt = 0
  for idx = 1 .. len(s)
    if s[idx] = c
      print idx - cnt
      res += idx - cnt
      cnt++
  removeAll(s, c)
return res
```

where

```
removeAll(s,c):
  i = 1
  cnt = 0
  n = len(s)
  while (i < n) 
    if s[i + cnt] = c
      cnt++
      n--
    else
      s[i] = s[i + cnt]
    i++
  len(s) = n
```

It prints the elements of the sum to better illustrate what's going on.

**Edit:**
An updated version based on Igor's answer, that does not require actually removing elements. The complexity is the same i.e. `O(n)`.

```
res = 0
for c in 'a' .. 'z'
  cnt = 0
  for idx = 1 .. len(s)
    if s[idx] <= c
      if s[idx] = c
        print idx - cnt
        res += idx - cnt
      cnt++
return res
```